# Can I use LINQ to give me a non-object view of items in a LIST?

Tags: c#, linq

I have these objects:

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}

public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through a list of `IJapaneseDictionary` 
and get the `Text` of all the `Kanjis`. Something like this:

```
Seq  KanjiText
1    abc
1    def
2    ghi
```

I can iterate through the list like this:

```
public static List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> jmdict;
foreach (var item in jmdict)
```

I'm familiar with

```
var a = item.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
```

But can I get the kanji one by one and output something like this for each item using LINQ or do I need to have another foreach for this:

```
Console.WriteLine(seq);
Console.WriteLine(kanji);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure I properly understood what you mean but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var result = jmdict.SelectMany(entry => entry.Kanjis.Select(k => (entry.Sequence, k.Text)));
```